# what's wrong with my while-loop php

Tags: php

Create a while-loop that subtracts 6.82 from the number 761 until the
number is between (not equal to) 23 and 33. Answer with the final result asa float, rounded to 2 decimals.

```
$f=761;
$b=6.82;
while (($f > 33)||($f < 23 )) {
$f=$f-$b;
$f++;

}
$ANSWER = round($f, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

I get the wrong answer, 27.68 instead of 31.26 on the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your loop, and before last `$f` equals `33.5` because of `$f++;` so it will loop once more. It is like:

```
f = 50.96
f = 45.14
f = 39.32
f = 33.5 // still higher than 33 so do it once more
f = 27.68 // and now is lower, get out
```

It seems like `$f++` is not necessary here.

You can check both codes:

[PHP Compiler](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/131d531f5dae9d9ce74ed90c2118768fba4d89a9)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the `$f++`.

Comment: You're correct, though it's still a mistery what is the purpose of this code.
You can check out the result withouth `$f++` [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e959d4e575094c2e03eca1b613e7a1dac61c7660)

Comment: I agree. Even the second condition `($f < 23 )` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this:

```
 $f++
```

Remove it